# Why is possible use expressions as statements?

Tags: c#, .net

There is a special reason which allows the use of expressions as statements?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Can you give an example of what you're talking about. Thanks

Comment: That's what I said, but was on a test

Answer (score 5):

Not all expressions can be used as statements, according to compiler error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

For all of them, it makes sense to use them alone (especially assignment!).

It's not as obvious why is new object expression allowed too, but I think it's not unreasonable to think that it can have observable side-effects.

The C# 4 specification talks about expression statements in section 8.6, but it doesn't say much else than the error message.

Comment: If you construct an object for the sole purpose of its side effects... Not necessarily good practise, but hey, stranger things have happened.

Answer (score 1):

The most famous reason would probably be `i++`.

Comment: It is an expression that is very commonly used as a standalone statement when iterating over arrays.

Answer (score 0):

No. Compatibility with other C-style languages, maybe. But hey, why not?

If you don't like it, don't use it.

Comment: @Ritch Melton: Things like `2 + 2;`, I take it.

Comment: @mintech, that doesn't compile.

Comment: @svick: Oh... um, I suppose it would be things like `new Object();` without any follow-up then. In that case, the answer is because constructors are pretty much like any other method - calling them may have an effect.

Comment: @minitech, well, (user-defined) operators are line any other method too, and you can't use them by themselves.

Comment: @svick: Reason = semantics. It doesn't make sense for `new A() + new B()` to have a side-effect.